# Strange characters when I type Arabic in VB6/Access

Tags: ms-access, datagrid, vb6, textbox, right-to-left

I have a problem with typing Arabic in VB6. I have an Access db with ADO connection, and every time I type in a text box to send it to the db, it looks good in the text box. When I navigate it looks fine but when I go back to the grid or to open the db in Access I see strange characters.

When I type anything in Arabic in the grid or in Access, it shows in the text box like `??????`

The Datagrid that I am using has the same problem.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: The link to your screenshot is broken. Try editing your original post and inserting the image via the image upload button.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?88q6uajuajia5#vwtcvxbo26obvns

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?88q6uajuajia5#2b35tuo69o6gbwd

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?88q6uajuajia5#d7b8zdtogz1hy7w

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?88q6uajuajia5#rv6e6x8l4ze16r4

Comment: Are you using bound controls or code to update the database? Can you show us any code on the form?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an "out of the box" VB6 textbox control. You must add a component reference to a textbox that supports Unicode. There is one freely available with Visual Basic 6 although it is not the default with within the toolbox/palette.